# distinguishing between indoor and outdoor by the gps provider

Tags: java, android

I would like to distinguish when my user is indoor and when he is outdoor using the gps provider.
That would be done by the getAccuracy() method of coruse.
So which value returned from the method would be the limit?

**from which value I will be sure that my user is indoor**?

Comment: Define "sure": how sure do you want to be? You'll be using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` when you're indoors, for one thing.

Comment: I provide 1 location each 10 minute. I'm using the gps provider as default since he is more accurate outdoor but when my user is indoor I should use the network provider. in other words if(gps.getAccuracy() > x){use network provider} .. x = ?

Comment: All you can really do is make educated guesses. You could be outdoor under dense tree-cover, in a vehicle, or in deep urban canyons, and get virtually no satellite reception, but plenty of wifi. Comparatively, you could be indoor on the top floor of a residence, and get excellent GPS but no wifi (or wifi might be disabled). 
So first define, as @DaveNewton asked, what "sure" means to you. Then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GPS there is no for "sure". 
I would suggest: If hor accuracy is 10m or better chances are good to be outdoors.

If you don't have any GPS signal. then you are probably indoors or just went outdoors.

In dense city areas outdoors accuracy can be higher than 10m.

Record, and display the GPS signal, and look what its gives for values indoors and outdoors.

In many/most building you will not have a GPS signal at all, unless you are sitting at the window. My iphone currently shows 65m indoors.

So start with that:

```
No GPS signal: indoors (or tunnel, garage)
hor accuracy > 20m : indoors
hor accuracy <= 10m:  outdoors
else grey zone
```

Comment: Sometimes the gps provide locations indoor but their accurate is very bad. so you are saying if the accuracy is larger then 10 meters I'm probably indoor?

Comment: outddors you should have 3-6m accuracy, which my iphone displays in steps of 5: (5,10).  However if you are near a window you also can have a good Gps Signal. You could distiguis: probaly outdoors, probaly indoors, grey zone

Comment: So a 10 meters should be the limit?

Comment: The limit depend which one should be sure: outdoor or indoors: in GPS outdoors is not the exact opposite of indoors, because of the grey zone.

Comment: does the weather affect the accuracy of the gps signal?

Comment: No, at least not that what we understand under weather (rain, snow, clouds). Mainly the ionospheric weather (sun disturbances) influence the signal. Therefore at night the signal is better, because no sun creates ionospheric effects.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
I.E if you can't get a location from GPSProvider but you can from network provider, you can assume you're indoors or underground

Comment: But sometimes the gps provides a location while I'm indoor but the accuracy is very bad.

Comment: then you have to decide an acceptable limit yourself, I don't think there's any "rules" about that

Comment: I know, so my question is what is the most acceptable limit? which I mean 200 meters limit is much better then 200km limit. I'm looking for the best limit(I know it's sounds wierd xD)